# google cloud machine learning tutorial error

Tags: python

I'm new to machine learning, today I follow this tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cpb102-txf-learning/index.html

But at step 5 I got an error

```
chuanman2707@transfer-learning-169510:~$ cd cloudml-samples/flowers
chuanman2707@transfer-learning-169510:~/cloudml-samples/flowers$ 
DICT_FILE=gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/dict.txt
chuanman2707@transfer-learning-169510:~/cloudml-samples/flowers$ 
PROJECT=$(gcloud config list project --format "value(core.project)")
chuanman2707@transfer-learning-169510:~/cloudml-samples/flowers$ 
BUCKET="gs://${PROJECT}-flower"
chuanman2707@transfer-learning-169510:~/cloudml-samples/flowers$ 
GCS_PATH="${BUCKET}/${USER}"
chuanman2707@transfer-learning-169510:~/cloudml-samples/flowers$ gsutil mb 
$BUCKET
Creating gs://transfer-learning-169510-flower/...
chuanman2707@transfer-learning-169510:~/cloudml-samples/flowers$ python 
trainer/preprocess.py \
>   --input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
>   --input_path "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/eval_set.csv" \
>   --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval" \
>   --cloud
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "trainer/preprocess.py", line 71, in <module>
import apache_beam as beam
ImportError: No module named apache_beam
```

Please help me go through this tutorial. Thank you.

**edit**
After I tried to install `pip install apache-beam` I got this:

> chuanman2707@transfer-learning-169510:~/cloudml-samples/flowers$ pip install apache-beam
>   Collecting apache-beam
>   Collecting avro<2.0.0,>=1.8.1 (from apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: mock<3.0.0,>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: crcmod<2.0,>=1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: grpcio<2.0,>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from apache-beam)
>   Collecting protobuf==3.2.0 (from apache-beam)
>     Using cached protobuf-3.2.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
>   Collecting oauth2client<4.0.0,>=2.0.1 (from apache-beam)
>   Collecting httplib2<0.10,>=0.8 (from apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml<4.0.0,>=3.12 in /home/chuanman2707/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: dill==0.2.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: funcsigs>=1; python_version < "3.3" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from mock<3.0.0,>=1.0.1->apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from mock<3.0.0,>=1.0.1->apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: pbr>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from mock<3.0.0,>=1.0.1->apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: enum34>=1.0.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from grpcio<2.0,>=1.0->apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: futures>=2.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from grpcio<2.0,>=1.0->apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from protobuf==3.2.0->apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: rsa>=3.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client<4.0.0,>=2.0.1->apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client<4.0.0,>=2.0.1->apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client<4.0.0,>=2.0.1->apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=16.8 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from setuptools->protobuf==3.2.0->apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from setuptools->protobuf==3.2.0->apache-beam)
>   Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->protobuf==3.2.0->apache-beam)
>   Installing collected packages: avro, protobuf, httplib2, oauth2client, apache-beam
>   Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
>       prefix=options.prefix_path,
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
>       **kwargs
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
>       self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
>       isolated=self.isolated,
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
>       clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
>       ensure_dir(destdir)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
>       os.makedirs(path)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
>       mkdir(name, mode)
>   OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/avro-1.8.2.dist-info'
>   chuanman2707@transfer-learning-169510:~/cloudml-samples/flowers$

What should I do next? Thank you

Comment: You have to install the module : `pip install apache-beam`

Comment: i got this error when i try to do the `code pip install apache-beam`

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully at the line: `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/avro-1.8.2.dist-info'`, you'll see that you need `sudo` permissions.

Run the following:

```
sudo pip install apache-beam
```

Comment: I got the same kind of error on glcoud shell, and your answer worked!!! Thanks @TheDarkKnight